# Return 0 1 instead of data values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple SELECT request

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, age, country
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id
```

returning somethink like

```
jean    dupont  35  france
hervé   yang        japon
laura           28  
mickael sylvain 65  suisse
...
```

I want returning 1 (or true) when the field is not null, and 0 (or false) when the field is null.

In my exemple, the request should return

```
1   1   1   1
1   1   0   1
1   0   1   0
1   1   1   1
...
```

Thanks for help

Comment: `case firstName when is null then 0 else 1 end;`

Comment: @xQbert looks like an answer to me

Comment: what if it is a blank value '', or white space ' ' only would that be true or false?  WHEN ... IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 would return that '' would have a value.  You many want to test for Length LEN() for string data types and trim spaces off the beginning and end of word.... WHEN LEN(ISNULL(LTRIM(RTRIM(field)),'')) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select boolean expressions directly to get `true` or `false` as your result.

```
SELECT
  firstname IS NOT NULL,
  lastname IS NOT NULL,
  age IS NOT NULL,
  country IS NOT NULL
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 2):

The cast from boolean to integer yields 0 or 1

```
select
    (firstname is not null)::integer as firstname,
    (lastname is not null)::integer as lastname,
    (age is not null)::integer as age,
    (country is not null)::integer as country
from mytable
order by id
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to substitute values consider using a case statement.  it's the most basic and generally supported in all RDBMS systems.

```
SELECT case firstName when is null then 0 else 1 end as col1
     , case lastname when is null then 0 else 1 end as col2 
     , case age when is null then 0 else 1 end as col3
     , case countrywhen is null then 0 else 1 end as col4
FROM mytable
ORDER BY id
```